# print all urls - python

Tags: python, url, hyperlink

I already created a get_url function that retrieves one url, I am now trying to call that function to define a different one, print_all_links(s), that prints all urls from an inputted string. This is what I have so far, it prints the correct amount of url's but they are just the first url repeated, and not on one line, please help

```
def get_url(s):
    #s = s.replace(" ", "")
    b = s.find('<a href=')
    if b != -1:
        return s[b + 9 : b + 9 + s[b + 9::].find('"')]
    else:
        return b

#prints all URls in HTML input
def print_all_links(s):
    i = s.count('<a href=')
    n = i
    x = ''
    while n > 0:
        x += get_url(s)
        print(x)
        s = s.replace(x, '')
        n = n-1
```

sample input: 
print_all_links('  **University of Illinois at Chicago**  |

prints: https://uic.edu
        https://uic.edu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
def get_url(s):
    #s = s.replace(" ", "")
    b = s.find('<a href=')
    if b != -1:
        return s[b + 9 : b + 9 + s[b + 9::].find('"')]
    else:
        return b

#prints all URls in HTML input
def print_all_links(s):
    i = s.count('<a href=')
    print(i)
    n = i
    x = ''
    while n > 0:
        x = get_url(s)
        print(x)
        s = s.replace('<a href="' + x, '')
        n = n-1
```